# 2D SortedList containing int and string, need the string of to the highest int

Tags: c#, arrays, string, loops, max

I have a 2D list which holds sentences and a score generated for that sentence, I need to get the sentence which has the highest score.

So the list is:

```
("This is sentence one", "302")
("And another sentence", "154")
("Oh and heres another", "528")
```

The function the list is formed and also where I need to get the sentence with the highest score is this:

```
    protected void buildSummary()
    {
        scoreCoord2 = -1;
        for (int x1 = 0; x1 < results.Length; x1++)
        {
            SortedList<int, string> paragraphScoreslist = new SortedList<int, string>();
            for (int x2 = 0; x2 < results[x1].Length; x2++)
            {
                scoreCoord2++;
                paragraphScoreslist.Add(intersectionSentenceScores[scoreCoord2], results[x1][x2]);
            }
            int maxValue = paragraphScoreslist.Max(k => k.Key);
            //string maxValue = paragraphScoreslist.TryGetValue;
            TextboxSummary.Text = maxValue.ToString();
        }
    }
```

I'm able to get the highest int value from the sorted list, but don't know how to get the string which is tied to it. I think I need to use TryGetValue but I don't know to use it in a 2D list which in of its self I haven't used before.

Comment: so basically you want to keep the x coordinate of the greatest element, and the access to the value at `(x_max, 0)`, is that correct?

Comment: If performance is a concern, you should keep track of the highest scoring sentence when you score each sentence. i.e., `highScore = score > highScore ? score : highScore`

Comment: otherwise, you can't really do better than an O(N) operation like `scores.OrderByDescending(x => x.Score).First()`

Comment: Using a 2D array seems to be adding needless complexity to this problem. Using a different container type would be much easier. For example, using a `List<Tuple<string, int>>` would then just be a simple matter of calling `list.OrderByDescending( tup => tup.Item2 )`.

Comment: @Didaxis I'd love to be able to keep track of the highest score before where I am now, but the score is based on the number of common words each sentence shares and that needs the existing array of Paragraphs > Sentences to loop though. tbh this whole thing has given me a massive headache so any bright notions would be great.

Comment: @TonyH. I defaulted to array as its what I've used the most for this sort of thing, the list use sounds great though s I didn't know you could 2D lists and specify a type for each.

Comment: @Tom, I'm missing something here, are you responsible for assigning these scores or not?

Comment: @Tom Because in a normal list you can't. A list is defined as `List<T>`, you are just taking advantage of generic and another object called `Tuple<T1,T2>`. Although a `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>` youle be more fitting for this problem. Also see my answer for a different take on the problem.

Comment: @Didaxis The point I'm at now is the earliest I can calculate the highest score for each paragraph, the program splits text into the jagged array of paragraph > sentences, then each sentence is compared to each other by being split into words and the number of common words is that sentences score against that sentence, in my current test text of 180 sentence this results in roughly 37.5 thousand values. The scores I'm dealing with in my question are where I loop through and add all the scores for each sentence together. Which leads to where I am now, theres no room prior to get the highest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have control over the array replace it with a SortedList and you can use the SortedList.Max() function without hassle. A sorted list is probably the best take on, as it inherently sorted (which you want), so getting the highest (i.e. Max value) will be faster than an unsorted array, or an unsorted List.

If you don't have control over the data you are receiving, project the data you are getting into a new form (the above SortedList

Going with the example you put up in your post, lets call it "matrix" for simplicity sake:

```
string[,] matrix = 
{
    { "This is sentence one", "302" }, 
    { "And another sentence", "154" },
    { "Oh and heres another", "528" }
};
```

Here is the code to put it into a sorted List:

```
// New instance, pretty simple
SortedList<int, string> list = new SortedList<int, string>();

// Loop through the array and project it into a new form
for(int i = 0; i <= matrix.Length(0); i++) {
        list.Add(Convert.ToInt32(matrix[i, 1]), matrix[i, 0]);
}

// Get the max value in the list
var maxValue = list.Max(k => k.Key);
```

Now you can do what you want with the value. If you want to get the sentence for it you should use the `TryGetValue` method, but that's up to you. Like this:

```
string sentence= string.Empty;
if (list.TryGetValue(maxValue, out sentence))
{
    // Do something with the string you got
}
```

For more information how to use the whole `Try...` methods you should read up on out and ref parameters.

Anything else?

Comment: I need the string and I'm not familiar with TryGetValue, I'm looking at the msdn page for it, but it isn't helping me apply it to the list scenario :/

Comment: @Tom I appended my answer with code how to get the sentence from the array.